# Error while opening the excel file created by NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, npoi

I am using NPOI to export the data to excel. I am forcing the file to be downloaded as an attachment for the user. When the user saves the file on the disk and opens the file it works but fails when he tries to select the open option from the download dialog box. Please see the code below. Not sure what is wrong

```
var xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet1 = xssfworkbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");

            //make  header row

            var row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);

            var cell0 = row1.CreateCell(0);
            cell0.SetCellValue("Firm Id");

            var cell1 = row1.CreateCell(1);
            cell1.SetCellValue("Account Number");

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = sheet1.CreateRow(i + 1);

                if (result[i].FeeAmount != null)
                {
                    var cellFirmID = row.CreateCell(0);
                    cellFirmID.SetCellValue(result[i].FirmID);
                }

                if (result[i].AccountNumber != null)
                {
                    var cellAccountNumber = row.CreateCell(1);
                    cellAccountNumber.SetCellValue(result[i].AccountNumber);
                }
}

System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "BESTINVEST_fee_rebate_loader_.xlsx"));
MemoryStream file = WriteToStream(xssfworkbook);
response.Clear();
response.BinaryWrite(file.ToArray());
response.End();





        private MemoryStream WriteToStream(XSSFWorkbook xssfworkbook)
        {
            MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
            xssfworkbook.Write(file);
            return file;
        }
```

Comment: What does the resulting file look like when you view the contents? Is it empty? If you change the extension to .zip and then try to open it, is there content there?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is from "culture". before Create excel:

```
var culture=new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=culture;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make sure your cells are unlocked.

I use the following without problems:

```
                var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var members = (obj as IEnumerable<MemberListViewModel>).ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(TempData["List"].ToString());
            var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

            headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Name");
            headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Degrees");
            headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Rank");
            headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Endowed Professorship");
            headerRow.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue("Department");
            headerRow.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue("Program");

            var font = workbook.CreateFont();
            font.Boldweight = (short)NPOI.SS.UserModel.FontBoldWeight.Bold;
            XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            style.SetFont(font);
            style.FillPattern = NPOI.SS.UserModel.FillPattern.SolidForeground;
            style.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.Grey25Percent.Index;
            style.IsLocked = false;
            style.WrapText = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                var colStyle = sheet.GetColumnStyle(i);
                colStyle.WrapText = !colStyle.WrapText;
                sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(i, colStyle);
                var cell = headerRow.Cells[i];
                cell.CellStyle = style;
            }
            headerRow.RowStyle = style;


            sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 30 * 256);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 20 * 256);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 20 * 256);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 50 * 256);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(4, 30 * 256);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(5, 50 * 256);

            int rowNumber = 1;
            style = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
            style.IsLocked = false;
            style.WrapText = true;
            foreach (MemberListViewModel member in members)
            {
                var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(member.FullName);
                row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(member.degrees);
                row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(member.rank);
                row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(member.endowed_professorship);
                row.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(member.department);
                row.CreateCell(5).SetCellValue(member.program);
            }
            //var colStyle = sheet.GetColumnStyle(3);
            //colStyle.WrapText = !colStyle.WrapText;
            //sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(3, colStyle);

            workbook.Write(output);

            var fileName = String.Format(
                            "{0} {2} - {1}.xlsx",
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"),
                            Utilities.getUsername(Utilities.GetCurrentUser()), TempData["List"]).Replace(":", "");
            var file = File(output.ToArray(), Utilities.ExcelFileContentType, fileName);

            var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("inline;filename=\'{0}\'", fileName));
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", file.FileContents.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer: file.FileContents.ToArray());
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
            output.Dispose();
```